# Powershell script to download package from NuGet

Tags: powershell, nuget, powershell-3.0, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I want to set up a local repository for developers, this repository will be used to install packages on projects in our internal team. How can I setup local repository using powershell? Like-I want to provide 100(suppose) packages to my developers through my local repository. Manually, I've to download all those packages from Nuget.org into my local repository. This is the task I want to automate, I want powershell to take the name and download these packages from Nuget.org to my local folder.

Thanks.

Comment: That will be incredibly tedious to maintain - every time a developer wants to use a new version of a package, they will have to also add an entry to your PowerShell file, and then run it. What are you hoping to achieve by doing this - there is probably a better way! Also, consider that there are some excellent NuGet servers that will automatically serve as mirrors/proxies of NuGet.org (we use ProGet internally for example).

Comment: Thanks for reply. We do want to have control on packages/versions being used in organisation. It may tedious in some way as you said. But I need to get this done for now..:P

Comment: Ok, so to download a file you can use the `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet, and the URL is easily constructed from the package name and version (see the Download link on every NuGet package for the format). What exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: I'm new to powershell so was not aware about the command. I'm trying it now.

Comment: It's giving me xml/html of the page but not starting download at all. Could you please help? For example I want to download EntityFramework package from Nuget.org to my local folder.

Answer (score 0):

ProGet has reasonably fine-grained permissions, including "pull" permissions (see https://inedo.com/support/documentation/proget/administration/security).

I would suggest that that using a ProGet server to proxy NuGet.org, and only giving certain users "Add Package" and "Pull Package" privileges will give you the control you require with much less frustration.

Note that making a NuGet repository out of a network share can cause performance issues, especially when you start getting into the hundreds of NuGet packages. NuGet will end up having to download each file each time you want to do most of the standard commands.

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to use any proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I was trying to find this solution too. RB's post gave me an idea and the missing piece was the -OutFile option.

---

### Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $s -OutFile ("c:\MyPackages\$pn")

With $s = to the path of the package and $pn = to the whole package name as you want it saved as will download the package to the specified path.

I recently had to migrate 100's of packages and was able to automate the process them by iterating through the packages and using the command above to get each one and put them where needed.